# Changing the randomized select algorithm affect on runtime

Tags: algorithm, performance, computer-science, analysis, pseudocode

What happens to Randomized select algorithm running time if we change line 8 in the code from q-1 to q in CLRS book page 216 ?

what I found is that algorithm should still work and there shouldn't be any change in running time since it depends only on RANDOMIZED PARTITION subroutine. Is it true ?

```
Randomized-Select (A,p,r,i)
// Finds the ith smallest value in A[p .. r].
if (p = r)
    return A[p]
q = Randomized-Partition(A,p,r)
k = q-p+1   // k = size of low side + 1 (pivot)
if (i = k)
    return A[q]
else if (i<k)
    return Randomized-Select(A,p,q-1,i)
else
    return Randomized-Select(A,q+1,r,i-k)
```

Answer (score 1):

I-th statistics might be in the:
left part - range p ..q-1
right part - range q+1..r
exactly at index q

The last case happens when condition fulfills:

```
if (i = k)
   return A[q]
```

otherwise we know that q-th element never will be i-th statistics, so it is not wise to treat it again and again at later iterations (recursion levels).

Proposed modification won't change complexity but real run time might increase a bit

(average case `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1=2n` vs `n + (n/2+1) + (n/4+1) + ... + 1=2n+log(n)`)

Comment: Does the corrupted code still work (that is, correctly find the ith smallest element) always, some-times, or never? I tried implementing the code in python but I'm getting an infinite loop.